# Adding django_content_type and permission without model

Tags: django, django-models, django-permissions

I want to have some permissions on few contents, which are NOT `models`, but are 'name' in the following table:

```
mysql> select * from my_contents;
+----+---------------------+
| id | name                |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | content1            |
|  2 | content2            |
```

I understand that **Django's Permission model requires a ContentType instance.** So, I also inserted these 2 entries in `django_content_type table` with arbitrary `app_label` and `model`.
Something like:

```
| 20 | content1  | some_label    | content1  |
| 21 | content2 | some_label     | content2  |
```

Now, I was thinking that on running `syncdb` permissions for these 2 new contents will be created automatically in `auth_permission`, but instead, I get:

```
The following content types are stale and need to be deleted:

    some_label | content1
    some_label | content2
```

How do I update the permissions for these 2 contents (without model) ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to do sounds like per object permissions. For each object within a model you want to set permissions on it. Django does not support this but [django-guardian](https://pythonhosted.org/django-guardian/userguide/assign.html) does. If you look at the link it provides a simple example on how to achieve this outcome.

If you really want to have a permission that does not have a matching model then have a look [at this snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/334/). Have not tested it personaly